# increment the copied string number javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have list of users and there is duplicate action to duplicate the selected user by suffixing **Copy**  to user name.

So if there is john username then duplicate action will create **john copy 1**  and if now user duplicate this "john copy 1" then there will be "john copy 2" and so on.

Here is the code, I am using

```
private _getDuplicateUserName(userName: string, suffixIndex): string {
    let _duplicateName;
    if (userName.includes("Copy")) {
        _duplicateName = userName.replace(/(\d+)+/g, (match, number) => {
            const index = parseInt(number, 10) + 1;
            return index.toString();
        });
        // for next iteration if this duplicate name exists
        userName = _duplicateName;
    } else {
        _duplicateName = `${userName} Copy ${suffixIndex}`;
    }
    console.log(_duplicateName);
    const _isSameName = this.users.find((_user: User) => _user.userName === _duplicateName);
    if (_isSameName) {
        return this._getDuplicateUserName(userName, suffixIndex + 1);
    } else {
        return _duplicateName;
    }
}
```

After creating the duplicate username i push the new user to `this.users` with duplicate username.

this works but problem is if there is username **john copy 1 copy 1** it duplicate it with **john copy 2 copy 2**.

I need to replace the last value only, need to change regex i guess, any help on this?

Comment: How do we know when we actually have encountered a username?  How do we know how many strings of `copy` might be present?

Comment: use `userName.replace(/.*\b(\d+)/g, ...` to get last number

Comment: @anubhava But we'd need a callback regex replacement here, to also do the increment `:-)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, i create new user with duplicate uer name and push it to users object.

Answer (score 1):

Simple task may be fix by simple logic, e.g. getting last char using array.length.

```js
var name = 'John';


function changeName(username) {

  if (username.includes('Copy')) {
    const last = username[username.length - 1]

    const count = parseInt(last) //check if valid integer

    if (count) {
      username = username.replace(/.$/, count + 1) //replace last char
    } else {
      username += ' Copy 1';
    }
  } else {

    username += ' Copy 1';
  }

  name = username;

  console.log('name', name);
}

changeName(name)
changeName(name)
changeName(name)
changeName(name)
changeName(name)
```

disclaimer: I don't think this is a good way to duplicate names. multiple people can copy John 2, and u get multiple John 3. and users can also name themselves 'Copy' and then your code breaks.